# Cross-Browser method for setting ScrollTop of an element?

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

For example I have I a div tag with the scroll bar on the right of the div tag.
I want to show the div with the last line, so I have this:

```
document.getElementById("divscroll").scrollTop = 250000;
```

I can make it scroll to the end in Firefox but never succcess with IE event with the bigger number!
Is there any simple Cross-borwser script (not JQuery or any big framework!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`scrollTop` works in all major browsers.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t35)

To scroll to the bottom of the element:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divscroll');
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight;
```

[`clientHeight` also works across browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t31), and [`scrollHeight` *mostly* works](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that **overflow** property is set:

```
<div id="divscroll" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
 //// something something 
</div>
```

Comment: And set height in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the scroll position to a real figure, instead of just an arbitrary big number:

```
document.getElementById("divscroll").scrollTop = document.getElementById("divscroll").scrollHeight;
```

Comment: `scrollHeight` will still be larger than the largest possible value of `scrollTop` (unless the element has zero height, but that's another problem).