# Javascript: Programmatically scroll non-popup SELECT element to bottom in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, select, scrolltop

I have a `SELECT` element in a web page, and I'd like it to load scrolled to the bottom.  In most browsers, I can do this:

```
myselect.scrollTop = myselect.scrollHeight;
```

Although `scrollHeight` is out of bounds, the browsers figure that out and limit it appropriately.  Except in Google Chrome.  I could file a bug report, but that doesn't help me with my immediate problem.  So I tried this:

```
myselect.scrollTop = myselect.scrollHeight - myselect.clientHeight;
```

But that subtracted too much -- there were items below the bottom of the element.  I also tried subtracting `offsetHeight`, but that was slightly worse.

Does anyone know a browser-agnostic way to properly calculate the `scrollTop` that is properly in-bounds so it'll work with Chrome?

BTW, I found this question on stackoverflow:  [Cross-Browser method for setting ScrollTop of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333028/cross-browser-method-for-setting-scrolltop-of-an-element).  Perhaps that works for DIVs, but not for SELECT elements and/or not in Chrome.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Here's an HTML page that demonstrates the problem:

```html
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.fields9{font-size:15px;height: 180px; width:420px; overflow: auto; border:1px solid #2d2b2d;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="myselect" class="fields9">
<option>firstone</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>lastone</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

element=document.getElementById("myselect");
//element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I view this in Chrome, the last option "lastone" is mostly cut off the bottom.  BUT, if I remove the `class="fields9"` attribute, the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle to show the problem because scrollHeight works in chrome, I use it all the time.

Comment: I hope the code I pasted in my edit is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of overflow: auto in fields9 declaration to make it work properly in Firefox and Chrome. Here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c4LDv/7/.

*Sadly, I wasn't able to find any solution for making it work in Opera - apparently you can't scroll select programatically in Opera...*

**Edit**: I've come up with a hackish approach, using selectedIndex to trigger scrolling to that last option. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/c4LDv/16/ it work in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. **However** - it won't scroll down to last option in Opera if one or more option is already selected (on page load) - see it here http://jsfiddle.net/c4LDv/15/ - I wasn't able to override this behavior.