# Issues setting scrollTop of element

Tags: javascript, scrolltop, childwindow

I have found many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333028/cross-browser-method-for-setting-scrolltop-of-an-element) with the same answers on how to do this but it just isn't working for me. I can see the scrollHeight of the element I am trying to set but the scrollTop value never changes from zero. The only possible difference from a standard application of setting scrollTop and my configuration is that I am attempting to set the scrollTop of an element in a child frame. I can access the element fine via selectors through the child frame and then I can see the scrollHeight as a correct value. Setting scrollTop just doesn't do anything.

*EDIT*

I figured out what was wrong. A height attribute needed to be set on the node I was trying to scroll to the end of. I had

.my-elem {
  overflow: scroll;
}

but needed

.my-elem {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}

Comment: I dont see any examples of your code. Explaining tbe situation is nice, but we need to see what youre actually. Like what you're setting the scrollTop as

Comment: Instead of putting the answer in your (edited) question, it would be more SO-like to answer your own question instead.